# cryptic message moving from tibble to data.table

Tags: r, data.table, tibble

Consider this simple example

```
mytib <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3),
                text = c('a','b','c'))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a text 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3     3 c
```

Now I need to use some magic `data.table` functions so I convert to `data.table` using `setDT()` which seems to work correctly:

```
mytib %>% setDT()
> mytib
   a text
1: 1    a
2: 2    b
3: 3    c
```

But now creating a new column by reference triggers this crazy error message.

```
> mytib[, newcol := text]
```

> Warning message: In `[.data.table`(mytib, , `:=`(newcol, text)) :
>   Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow)
>   copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by
>   reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R
>   (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid key<-,
>   names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole
>   data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames
>   and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use
>   case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or
>   this message improved.

Should I be concerned?
Thanks!

Comment: Fyi https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1894

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit strange - probably something to do with the conversion, and probably an error.

After a bit of testing it appears this only happens the first time you want to modify a data.table after conversion.

```
mytib <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3),
            text = c('a','b','c'))

mytib %>% setDT()
mytib[,newcol := text] # add initially - causes a warning, but still completes
mytib[,newcol := NULL] # removes fine
mytib[,newcol := text] # works fine - no error
```

Since the result returns fine and subsequently does not fire any warnings it is probably ignorable.

Note that this error happens seemingly regardless of what you are converting from - a list, dataframe or tibble, and regardless of whether you are copying a column that is already there or creating a completely new column.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just call the 'setDT' function directly instead of using the "%>%" operator?  This might have something to do with it since "data.table" uses "references" to access the data and this might be causing the problem.  I tried it with just the call directly, and it worked fine:

```
> library(data.table)

> library(tidyverse)

> mytib <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3),
+                 text = c('a','b','c'))
> setDT(mytib)
> mytib[, newcol := 'text']
>
```